# Alternative SQL ways of looking up multiple items of known IDs?

Tags: sql

Is there a better solution to the problem of looking up multiple known IDs in a table:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id='1001' OR id='2002' OR id='3003' OR ...
```

I can have several hundreds of known items. Ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE ID IN ('1001', '1002', '1003')
```

and if your known IDs are coming from another table

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT KnownID FROM some_other_table WHERE someCondition 
)
```

Answer (score 9):

The first (naive) option:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id IN ('1001', '2002', '3003' ... )
```

However, we should be able to do better.  `IN` is very bad when you have a lot of items, and you mentioned hundreds of these ids.  What creates them?  Where do they come from? Can you write a query that returns this list?  If so:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table 
INNER JOIN ( your query here) filter ON some_table.id=filter.id
```

Answer (score 3):

See [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

Answer (score 2):

ORs are notoriously slow in SQL.

Your question is short on specifics, but depending on your requirements and constraints I would build a look-up table with your IDs and use the EXISTS predicate:

```
select t.id from some_table t 
where EXISTS (select * from lookup_table l where t.id = l.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed set of IDs you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id IN (1001, 2002, 3003);
```

For a set that changes each time, you might want to create a table to hold them and then query:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id IN 
  (SELECT id FROM selected_ids WHERE key=123);
```

Another approach is to use collections - the syntax for this will depend on your DBMS.

Finally, there is always this "kludgy" approach:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE '|1001|2002|3003|' LIKE '%|' || id || '|%';
```

Comment: PLEASE steer clear of the LIKE option.  String conversions are slow, string comparisons are slow, and LIKE '%...%' means indexes can not be used.  I can not overstate how much this option should be avoided (imo).

Answer (score 0):

In `Oracle`, I always put the `id`'s into a `TEMPORARY TABLE` to perform massive `SELECT`'s and `DML` operations:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE t_temp (id INT)


SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   mytable.id IN
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    t_temp
        )
```

You can fill the temporary table in a single client-server roundtrip using `Oracle` collection types.

Comment: First of all, they produce no REDO and no UNDO, which means they're about 20 times faster than permanent ones.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar issue in an application written for MS SQL Server 7.  Although I dislike the solution used, we're not aware of anything better...

'Better' solutions exist in 2008 as far as I know, but we have Zero clients using that :)

We created a table valued user defined function that takes a comma delimited string of IDs, and returns a table of IDs.  The SQL then reads reasonably well, and none of it is dynamic, but there is still the annoying double overhead:
1. Client concatenates the IDs into the string
2. SQL Server parses the string to create a table of IDs

There are lots of ways of turning '1,2,3,4,5' into a table of IDs, but the Stored Procedure which uses the function ends up looking like...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_road_to_hell @IDs AS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN

   SELECT
      *
   FROM
      myTable
   INNER JOIN
      dbo.fn_split_list(@IDs) AS [IDs]
         ON [IDs].id = myTable.id

END
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest is to put the ids in another table and JOIN

```
SELECT some_table.* 
FROM some_table INNER JOIN some_other_table ON some_table.id = some_other_table.id
```

where some_other_table would have just one field (ids) and all values would be unique